# How to get a FOR loop to add numbers

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I can't figure out how to get a FOR loop to add a series of numbers and OUTPUT a total. What am I do doing wrong?

```
public class FOR
        {
        public static void main (String [] arsg)
                {
                int yellow, sumt, sum;


                sum=0;
                sumt=yellow;

                for (int number=1; number<=4; number++)
                        {
                        sum=ConsoleInput.readInt("enter");
                        yellow=sum+number;

                        }


                System.out.println("total is"+sumt);
                System.exit(0);
                }
        }
```

Comment: What language is tis supposed to be?

Comment: This class name is hurting my feelings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made some modification like this:

```
public class FOR
        {
        public static void main (String [] args)
                {
                int number, sum;
                sum=0;

                for (int i=1; i<=4; i++)
                        {
                        number=ConsoleInput.readInt("enter");
                        sum += number;
                        }

                System.out.println("total is" + sum);
                System.exit(0);
                }
        }
```

What was wrong in the provided code is that in the for loop you always added the loop variable to the currently read value. And you print out a value that was not even set in the loop. The loop variable has nothing to do with the sum. It just have to be used to control the number of how many times the for loop to be executed. You have to add the currently read value to the sum of the values read before.

Answer (score 0):

this should be done like this ..

```
            sum=0;
            sumt=0;

            for (int number=1; number<=4; number++)
                    {
                    sum =ConsoleInput.readInt("enter");
                    sumt += sum;    
                    }


            System.out.println("total is"+sumt);
            System.exit(0);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public class FOR
    {
    public static void main (String [] args)
            {
            int sum;
            for (int index =0; index < args.length(); index++)
                   sum += args[index];
            System.out.println("total is" + sum);
            System.exit(0);
            }
    }
```

just export this project to a runnable jar file ,then open your terminal , type:
"java -jar test.jar 1 2 3 4 5 " ,ended with an enter
you will get the answer
"total is 15".

Comment: @MarounMaroun,you don't know what's that?